# How to override the path of PHP to use the MAMP path?

Tags: php, macos, shell, path, mamp

After screwing up entirely my PHP configuration on MAC trying to get the SOAP module working (-bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory
....) I now have to use MAMP but each time I have to type the path

```
Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php to do command line.
```

**How to just type php instead the entire path on MAC ?** I double checked and i do not have a file named `.profile` nor `bash_profile`

Thanks

PS: Here's what output echo $PATH :

```
echo $PATH
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everytime you save MAMP config (PHP section), it saves the current version of PHP on `~/.profile` file and creates the alias for php, pear and pecl, to point to the current configured version. (Note: you need to check "Make this version available on the command line" option in MAMP)

However, you need to refresh your terminal (open another session) to get this file refreshed. You can also type `source ~/.profile` to refesh the aliases manually.

If you want to extract this curerent version in a PHP_VERSION variable - as commented above - for further use, you can do:

```
export PHP_VERSION=`grep "alias php" ~/.profile | cut -d"/" -f6 | cut -c4-`
```

And then you'll have $PHP_VERSION available with the current version of MAMP.

Finally, if you want to **run your php using the current configured version on mamp**, you just need to add to your `~/.bash_profile` the following:

```
export PHP_VERSION=`grep "alias php" ~/.profile | cut -d"/" -f6 | cut -c4-`
export PHPRC="/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/" #point to your php.ini folder to use the same php settings
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php$PHP_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Now, even script that relies on `/usr/bin/env php` will read the correct version from Mamp config.

Comment: Is the auto update of .profile a PRO version thing, only?  I've always had to manually update .profile for as long as I've been using MAMP (~10 years)

Answer (score 130):

In your home folder `/Users/David` for exmaple, you can create a `.bash_profile`. In here you can export variables and then add them to your path.

Open up the file to edit it in your favourite editor, I use vim.

Then you can add in your path

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

You want your bit ahead of the `$PATH` as that already includes `/usr/bin` which is where the system PHP lives. So the system will always find your MAMP version first.

Save this file and then reboot your Terminal and you'll see that you should get your MAMP version.

To test I use `php -v` as OSX Lion uses 5.3.10 and my MAMP is using 5.3.6
You can also test using `which php` which will output the path to your current php executable.

Comment: Worked like magic. I tried upgrading default php that comes with mac but no luck. finally now PATH of php points my MAMP's php.

Comment: I know this post is a little bit old, but maybe it can help someone.
If you're using MAMP with oh-my-zsh, you should put these DavidYell lines in ~/oh-my-zsh/.zshrc file.

You'll find the "export PATH" line (at least now in my current updated version) on line 54. Put the DavidYell's lines jst AFTER that. For me, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 116):

The fact that the previously accepted answer refers to php 5.3.6, while the current version of MAMP ships with 7.2.1 as the default (as of early 2018), points out that this is not a very sustainable solution. You can make your path update automatically by adding an extra line to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` to get the latest version of PHP from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/` and export that to your path. Here’s how I do it:

```sh
# Use MAMP version of PHP
PHP_VERSION=`command ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

(Use `source ~/.bash_profile` after making your changes to make sure they take effect.)

As others have mentioned, you will likely also want to modify your shell to use MAMP’s mysql executable, which is located in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin`. However, I do *not* recommend exporting that folder, because there are a bunch of other executables there, like `libtool`, that you probably don’t want to be giving priority to over your system installed versions. This issue prevented me from installing a node package recently (libxmljs), as documented [here](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/issues/305#issuecomment-93700249).

My solution was to define and export `mysql` and `mysqladmin` as functions:

```
# Export MAMP MySQL executables as functions
# Makes them usable from within shell scripts (unlike an alias)
mysql() {
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql "$@"
}
mysqladmin() {
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin "$@"
}
export -f mysql
export -f mysqladmin
```

I used functions instead of aliases, because aliases don’t get passed to child processes, or at least not in the context of a shell script. The only downside I’ve found is that running `which mysql` and `which mysqladmin` will no longer return anything, which is a bummer. If you want to check which mysql is being used and make sure everything is copacetic, use `mysql --version` instead.

Note: @julianromera points out that zsh doesn’t support exporting functions, so in that case, you’re best off using an alias, like `alias mysql='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql'`. Just be aware that your aliases might not be available from subshells (like when executing a shell script).

Comment: This solution is elegant, sustainable, and absolutely genius. Thank you!

Comment: export function does not work on zsh. What about using an alias? (e.g `alias mysql='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql'`)

Comment: @julianromera I started with aliases, but in my experience, aliases don’t get passed to child processes, or at least not in the context of a shell script. So if I run a shell script that uses mysql, it won’t find my alias and will instead use the system version of mysql. Anyways, thanks for the tip! I’ll add a note about zsh.

Comment: This is a very cool way to do this, BUT the latest version of PHP on MAMP is 7 and most apps will break using that version. I wonder if theres a way to get the current default from a conf file?

Comment: @Christian That’s a great point. Certainly would be possible to read a file to get the current active MAMP PHP version, but I don’t work with PHP anymore, so I don’t have MAMP installed. Makes it hard to explore. Could you look into your MAMP config to find the file that would have that info and post a copy of it, along with the path to where it is located?

Comment: interesting that setting an alias for ```php``` to the MAMP binary doesn't work in El Capitan, but adding the bin directory to PATH does. anyone know why? thanks!

Comment: what if you need to step back a version and not use the latest version of PHP, running into issues with Drush and Drupal. Can the above be modified: ```PHP_VERSION=ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1``` or does it need to be hard coded, as shown in @david's solution?

Comment: If you want to explicitly avoid using the latest version of PHP, I would figure out what exact version you want to use and hardcode it into the path, like in David Yell’s solution.

Comment: Using 'command' ahead of the ls allows for pre-existing ls aliases to be ignored: command ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1

Comment: @AndrewPatton this doesn't work anymore on Mac Catalina :(

Comment: @FredK that’s too bad! maybe that’s because the new default interactive shell is now zsh. you could try taking the lines i suggested adding to your .bash_profile and instead add them to .zprofile in your home directory, if you have one.

Comment: @AndrewPatton I've not moved to zhs

Comment: I got this working in Catalina by putting Andrew's code at the top of the `.zshrc` file instead.

Answer (score 13):

I found that on Mavericks 10.8 there wasn't a .bash_profile and my paths were located in /etc/paths

In order to have the new path (whether this is a mamp or brew install of php) take effect it needs to be above the default /usr/bin/php in this paths file. eg.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
/usr/bin
```

AFter the change, open a new terminal window and run 'which php' that should now point to your updated path

Comment: On Yosemite here. In my case doing `which php` before your suggestion still produced the correct path (since I had the path in my .bash_profile) but phpinfo() wasn't showing mcrypt (or any other extensions in my php.ini) as loaded. Doing this fixed that however, so thanks!

Comment: You should be creating your own `.bash_profile` in your home folder so your changes only impact you.

Answer (score 10):

you might still run into mysql binary not being found in that manner

```
open terminal, type
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

edit as follows below, save, quite and restart terminal or alternately

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to execute new PATH without restarting terminal

and in the fashion of the DavidYell's post above, also add the following. You can stack various variables by exporting them followed by a single PATH export which I demonstrated below

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin
export MAMP_BINS=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
export USERBINS=~/bins
export PATH="$USERBINS:$MAMP_PHP:$MAMP_BINS:$PATH"
```

cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you have to type

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php
```

in your command line then add

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin
```

to your PATH to be able to call php from anywhere.

Comment: yeap but how to add it to the PATH variable please ?

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin
You may have to restart / reconnect your terminal for it to work (at least with different ones open in parallel).

Comment: it seem this not permanent. when i open new terminal. it use default MAC php path at `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: For permanent storage you’ll have to save it not only to your local, temporary PATH but to your systems path. Although I’m not familiar with MAC it should probably be `export PATH` to persistate it after you set it (modified it).

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of MAMP (Version 5+) offers an easy way to make the MAMP PHP version available to the command line. Just select "PHP" in the the side bar menu and check "Make this version available on the command line". Easy peasy! See attached screenshot:)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/~php
sudo ln -s /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 2):

For XAMPP users you can use this:

```sh
# Use XAMPP version of PHP
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And you can check it with:

```sh
php -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's easier to do this:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php /usr/bin/php;`

Mamps version of PHP at the time of posting was `php5.6.10`, so make sure you change that to the version you're using.

You'll be up in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to comment but here's what I did when I ran into issues with setting php PATH for my XAMPP installation on Mac OSX

1. Open up the file .bash_profile (found under current user folder) using the available text editor.
2. Add the *path* as below:

export PATH=*/path/to/your/php/installation/bin*:**leave/rest/of/the/stuff/untouched/**:$PATH

3. Save your .bash_profile and re-start your Mac.

Explanation: Terminal / Mac tries to run a search on the **PATHS** it knows about, in a hope of finding the program, when user initiates a *program* from the "Terminal", hence the trick here is to make the terminal find the php, the user intends to, by pointing it to the user's version of PHP at some bin folder, installed by the user.

Worked for me :)

P.S I'm still a lost sheep around my new Computer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an ideal solution as you have to manage two ini files however, I managed to work around this on windows by copying the php ini file in mamp from the conf folder to your active php version in the bin folder.

`[MAMP INSTALL]\conf\[ACTIVE PHP VERSION]\php.ini`

copy to

`[MAMP INSTALL]\bin\php\[ACTIVE PHP VERSION]`

Answer (score 0):

To compliment the current accepted answer, if you assume that MAMP uses the most recent version of php5 as the default, you can add grep 'php5' in the middle:

```
PHP_VERSION= `ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | grep 'php5' | tail -1`
```

and you are guaranteed to get the most recent php5 regardless of MAMP version.

Comment: I had hoped this would work, but I just get `-bash: php5.6.10: command not found` when I source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: It seems to me that your bash is trying to execute php5.6.10 which is weird.
The intended usage is
    `PHP_VERSION= 'ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | grep 'php5' | tail -1'`
    `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH`