# change the PHP path to MAMPs PHP

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I'm running PHP with MAMP on OSX 10.5.8

So if I want to run a script from console I always need to write

```
/applications/mamp/bin/php5.3/bin/php path/to/script
```

which is annoying. Is there a way to change the default path to php so that I can write

```
php path/to/script
```

and still uses MAMPs PHP version?

Comment: Add that directory to your `PATH`, see http://keito.me/tutorials/macosx_path

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a file called `.bash_profile` on your home directory (if you don't have this file already), and add this to the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/mamp/bin/php5.3/bin:$PATH
```

Then quit and relaunch Terminal.app

Comment: In my case, PHP was already installed using macports.

Removing macport's PHP was required for this solution to work: `$ sudo port uninstall php*` .

Answer (score 9):

## Use latest MAMP version of PHP

> you need to edit .bash_profile

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile
```

> if you cannot find bash_profile under your home directory then create .bash_profile:

```
 touch ~/.bash_profile
```

> Use latest MAMP version of PHP

```
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

(Run `source ~/.bash_profile` after making your changes to make sure they take effect.)

source: [How to override the path of PHP to use the MAMP path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way would be to rewrite the alias. Just copy/paste the cmd bellow into terminal for temporary use or write it into .bash_profile to make it permanent.

For MAMP

```
$ alias php=/applications/mamp/bin/php5.3/bin/php
```

For XAMPP

```
$ alias php=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php
```

For AMPPS

```
$ alias php=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/php
```

Run php via our new alias

```
$ php -v
```

Answer (score 4):

```
vi ~/.bash_profile

//add
export PATH=/path/to/php/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to bfvarettos great answer: since .bash_profile executes at login, you will need to restart your system for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is specific to MAMP 3.0 or not but you need to do the following path for MAMP 3.0.  Make sure you change the PHP version to the version you are using for your server.

Again this goes in ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH
```