# I can't install laravel on mac

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, installation

This is my error, I found it on google, and I don't know where is the error. I have MAMP PRO with php 5.4.4 version

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v4.2.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a virtualbox with debian.

- virtualbox: https://www.virtualbox.org
- debian: https://www.debian.org
- web server install tut:
  http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-lamp-server-with-apache2-php5-mysql-on-14.04-lts

or install homestead: http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

And read this: https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/development-environments-with-vagrant-and-puppet

Comment: thanks I'll try it! I have some errors on mac! I forgive it option! i want to try MEAN Stack, but still the same problem. I can't understand nothing!

Answer (score 5):

OS X is pre-installed with its own PHP, and it's probably older than 5.4 that Laravel 4.2 requires. And when you do `php` in your terminal, you'll probably get your OSX's php. Try it with `php -v`

You'll need to make your MAMP PRO's php your default binary, as suggested in [change the PHP path to MAMPs PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857068/change-the-php-path-to-mamps-php) Try:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMPPRO/php5.4.4/bin:$PATH
```

This will only work up until you close your terminal. To make the change permanent, add the line above to your `~/.bash_profile`

Then you check again by typing `which php` to your terminal. It should now point to your MAMP PRO's PHP binary.

Comment: I'll try it but nothing :(((

Comment: @Luiggi what does it say when you do `which php` and `php -v`?

Comment: php -v:PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Comment: php --> it's waiting too time

Comment: This solution does work indeed. Luiggi, i guess you just misspelled something there in your path entry.

Answer (score 3):

Use homestead , its a vagrant box that will help your development.

https://github.com/laravel/homestead

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are comfortable with the terminal, installing Apache & PHP, you can use MacPorts to install any version of PHP >= 5.4.

[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try in a few minutes, then if I can't install, I will use AngularJs to develop my admin.

Comment: This would help : http://scotty-t.com/2012/09/19/installing-php-5-4-like-a-boss-with-macports/