# Artisan cannot connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, mamp, laravel-artisan

I am running a local MAMP machine on my Mac.  Laravel running in production environment. Laravel is able to access the MySQL DB on php pages I display through the browser, yet when I am running `php artisan migrate` in Terminal, I receive

```
[PDOException]                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

`app/config/database`:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'laravel1',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'port'      => '8889'
),
```

ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:

Adding `'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'` (path designated in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`) to `app/config/database`.

Results in error:

```
[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your root password is 'root'?

Comment: I would have hoped that the fact that everything works in my browser assures the user and pw are correct as my Laravel site is able to connect to the database using `root` / `root`. Is this a false assumption?

Comment: How did you define your environments?

Comment: I have done nothing to modify environments. All I have touched in config are the above provided database details for production environment. What are environments defined for and where is it done - what should I do?

Comment: I think artisan is using you CLI version of PHP which is different from what MAMP uses. Try running `which php` in the console and compare with your `phpinfo()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. phpinfo() shows `Loaded Configuration File` as `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini`, whereas `which php` in Terminal returns `/usr/local/php5-5.5.16-20140822-215341/bin/php`. What now?

Comment: Cheers! Problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Ran `which php` in terminal, then ran `phpinfo()` on site. Found out different versions of php were used by MAMP and Terminal.
Fixed using [THIS METHOD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857088/2781619). Everything works thanks to [@cecilozaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243033).