# Allow composer to install laravel 4 and detect MAMP's PHP version not system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

new to composer and the like and have hit an issue.

When trying to download all the files using:

```
composer create laravel/laravel laravelNew
```

I see this error:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.0)
- Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.0)
Loading from cache

Created project in laravelNew
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.8 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.7 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.6 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.5 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.11 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.10 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

I am on a mac with PHP 5.3 installed, and this is confirmed when doing php -v

```
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 18:30:38)
```

However, I use MAMP to run my websites locally.

Is there a way I can tell the composer to check for the MAMP php version instead? Since the MAMP PHP version is 5.4+

Thanks. Craig.

Comment: You should upgrade your CLI version of PHP to match the MAMP version. Maybe MAMP also delivered a CLI version that you can link to. Not being a Mac user, I cannot suggest a solution. However, Composer cannot be made to think it is running under a different PHP version, so the answer to your last question is "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell your mac to use the latest version of php that you are using with Mamp. You do that in your .bash_profile.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857068/change-the-php-path-to-mamps-php) for more info.