# PHP --version shown incorrectly on osX

Tags: php, macos

I've installed in my osX php7 from homebrew, however when I type in the shell either`php --version` or `php-fpm --version` I get as result an older version

`PHP 5.5.30 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:22:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies`

From the shell I looked for every php file or folder `sudo find / -name "php"` but nothing linked to PHP 5.5

What should I do?

Comment: maybe you have more than one version installed

Comment: 1) Call a `phpinfo()` in a php page and open-it in browser. BTW, The 3rd part releases of php don't replace default php installation. You have to call-it  directly or add setting. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed) or - if it's don't work on your osx version - google-it something like 'php homebrew osx default'

Comment: @AlessioMTX Maybe one of this can help-you: https://goo.gl/0YQrtu  https://goo.gl/dvA4MI

Comment: phpinfo() shows 5.5.30, that is the dafault version installed in mac osx el capitan. Moreover, I use nginx, not apache

Comment: Most likely because the homebrew php is not in your bath. Use can add it in your `~/.bash_profile` (or whatever shell you use, bash is default on Mac). Add this to the end: `export /usr/local/Cellar/php7/bin:$PATH`  change the path to whatever is in your system.

Comment: export /path/that/need : not a valid identifier after source ~/.base_profile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After creating ~/.bash.profile as written in comments by Michael, I found the solution thanks to [change the PHP path to MAMPs PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857068/change-the-php-path-to-mamps-php)

In ~/.bash_profile I wrote:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.2/sbin:$PATH
```

First row is for php, the second for php-fpm

Then, to be sure that changes take effect type in terminal `source ~/.bash_profile`