# Why do I get this error when running aliases

Tags: php, command-line-interface, zsh

When installing codeception my aliases no longer work.  I have tried with both zsh and bash.  When I try to run one line cr I get this message

> ```
> env: php: No such file or directory
> ```

I am using a Mac and running the terminal inside VScode.  I have the aliases defined in ~/.zshrc

They were working and I verified that the codecept bin is in the correct location.  Now any cli gives me this message.

```html
alias pu='vendor/bin/phpunit'
alias co='vendor/bin/codecept'
alias cr='vendor/bin/codecept run'
alias crf='vendor/bin/codecept run functional'
alias cri='vendor/bin/codecept run integration'
alias cru='vendor/bin/codecept run unit'
alias cra='vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance'
export COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=~/.composer
export DOCKER_UIDGID=502:20
#alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php'
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
```

Comment: I suspect there's a CRLF line ending on the `export PATH` line.

Comment: And probably all the rest.

Comment: Here is my PATH
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/

Comment: you can't see the `\r` at the end.

Comment: The aliases worked previously and I haven't edited the file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the aliases.

Comment: That error indicates a problem with $PATH.

Comment: When I type php it works fine.  I don't understand the env: php: No such file or directory error

Comment: That's coming from running a script that starts with `#!/usr/bin/env php`

Comment: I thought you said that you get that error when you run any command.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP means any PHP command, not any command at all?

Comment: Sorry.  When I run any alias i get this error message.

Comment: If your PHP is in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php`, then you're going to have to update the PATH with the bin directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857068/change-the-php-path-to-mamps-php

Comment: @aynber. When I added the php path it fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: I can mark your solution as the answer to my question.