# unable to upgrade php5.3 to php 5.5 in my mac

Tags: php, macos

I want to upgrade my php to php 5.5 to works with Laravel framework .
I search about that and found this steps

- execute this command in terminal (curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5)
  and also try this blog 
  http://php-osx.liip.ch/

but on my mac there is no response and still my php is 5.3

can you please help me ?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow, can you please share code with us?

Answer (score 0):

First, try restarting your Mac.
Second, what do you use for Apache Services? MAMP/XAMPP?

Comment: i try to restart my mac and still not updated , umm i'm using MAMP

Comment: Download that, open your mamp folder and delete your PHP folder, and put the files in the zip and restart MAMP and it should do the trick for you. :P

Comment: Thanks, i solve it by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path