# How to configure PHPUnit in MAMP with PHAR

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I wanna test my php codes and I have decided to user PHPUnit for my test.

I have followed steps with  [official documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.5/en/installation.html#installation.phar)

```
 $ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
 $ chmod +x phpunit.phar
 $ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
 $ phpunit --version
 PHPUnit x.y.z by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

But I am using MAMP with my MacOS X.

So I am not sure how to implement PHAR files in MAMP.

Normally, the documentation tells to use this comment in terminal:

```
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

And my PHP location is:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/
```

I've tried to run this comment:

```
sudo mv phpunit.phar /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/
```

I don't know what should I do at this step. Please take a look because it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps I used to successfully get PHPUnit working in MAMP. These instructions
are pieced together from various places. I hope that having it all in one place helps
someone else. Happy testing!

## Use MAMP's PHP in the Terminal

Adapted from [How to override the path of PHP to use the MAMP path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667)

Edit or create `~/.bash_profile` with the lines below

```
# Use MAMP's latest version of PHP
MAMP_LATEST_PHP=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${MAMP_LATEST_PHP}/bin:$PATH
```

Place these lines after any other lines exporting $PATH - this assures that your MAMP PHP is found first in the path. Note that these lines try to find the highest numbered version of PHP in your MAMP installation. Feel free to adjust this to a specific one that you have, if desired.

You can tell you did it right when you get a MAMP path from `which php` in your terminal. You should get something like this:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php`

## Install PHPUnit

Mostly, this is downloading the PHP archive (PHAR) from the PHPUnit website. There are ways to do this from the command line that I couldn't get to work. So, I used a web browser.

1. Download the most recent PHPUnit PHAR from https://phar.phpunit.de
2. Move it to `/usr/local/bin`
3. `cd /usr/local/bin`
4. Make it executable with `chmod +x phpunit-5.3.2.phar` (adjust according to actual name)
5. Make a symbolic link with `ln -s phpunit-5.3.2.phar ./phpunit` (adjust according to actual name)
6. Check the version with `phpunit -—version`

You should get something like this:

`PHPUnit 5.3.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`

Building a symbolic link in step 5 permits you to use `phpunit` instead of having to type
`phpunit-5.3.2.phar` instead. It also allows you to update PHPUnit without having to 
change what you type, assuming of course that you create a new symbolic link when you
update.

## Write a Test

This isn't an exhaustive section. There are far better tutorials on writing tests.
Instead, this is merely some notes from my experience on rules that tripped me up,
though I'm sure everyone else knows them:

1. Your test class name must end with Test:
   `class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`
2. Your test class file name must end with Test.php and match the contained class:
   `SomeTest.php`
3. Method names in your test class that are to be run as tests must start with test:
   `public function testSomething()`

## Run a Test

By this time, it should be as easy as:

`phpunit SomeTest`

If everything goes well, PHPUnit will run your test and give you the results.

## Add a Handy Alias

Assuming that it all works (Yay!) try this alias in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Use colors when running phpunit
alias phpunit='phpunit --colors'
```

Comment: One line you forgot to mention after adding the lines to the bash file. "Use source ~/.bash_profile after making your changes to make sure they take effect."

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/bin/` is just recommended as a convention, because it's always in the $PATH on Unix systems, you can use any other location that's in your path, or leave it anywhere else and specify the absolute path when using it.

With what you have, you should be able to run:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/phpunit.phar --version
```

Note the `.phar` suffix, because you did not rename the file while moving, as you'd have with `sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit`

Answer (score 0):

I tried. You can use this command. It worked for me.

```
sudo mv phpunit.phar /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/phpunit
```