# Fish Shell - How to set a variable path in PATH

Tags: php, mysql, shell, mamp, fish

I want to update my fish shell to use the current version of php from MAMP (which ever version is currently in use).

I found an excellent article on how to do this in bash, but I can't seem to work out how to achieve this in fish?

The article is: [How to override the path of PHP to use the MAMP path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path)

Specifically:

```
# Use MAMP version of PHP
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

How do you achieve this in fish? Fish wants to export `PHP_VERSION` as a string.

And also using these commmand alias's to use current version of MySQL

```
# Export MAMP MySQL executables as functions
# Makes them usable from within shell scripts (unlike an alias)
mysql() {
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql "$@"
}
mysqladmin() {
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin "$@"
}
export -f mysql
export -f mysqladmin
```

I have tried to figure out the various pieces of this, but having limited understanding of commandline makes it difficult to know what to 'search' for.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7):

Setting PATH is covered in the [fish tutorial](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path).

Ordinarily you could simply modify `fish_user_paths`, but since you want the path to be dynamically determined on every launch, it's simpler to set PATH directly. A straightforward translation:

```
set PHP_VERSION (ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1)
set -x PATH /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/$PHP_VERSION/bin $PATH
```

You would put that in `~/.config/fish/fish.config`

Regarding "exporting functions", this was always a suspicious idea (it was the source of that terrible bash security hole) and is not something that fish supports. You should just instead arrange for `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql` to be in PATH, so that child scripts can find your executables. Just like before:

```
set -x PATH /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ $PATH
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, but it's still not working. It still only shows the the highest version, not the current one. 
Is it actually possible to detect which version MAMP is currently using and then set that in $PATH (dynamically)

Comment: I should restructure my question and repost I think. First - How to determine the version of PHP mamp is using dynamically. Because running `ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1` returns `total 0` and secondly then how to dynamically set that.

Comment: add this to my fish.config file successfully change my command line php version, thanks!