# wp-cli: unable to run phpunit on MAMP

Tags: bash, wordpress, mamp, wp-cli

I'm following the [plugin test setup/install instructions](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Plugin-Unit-Tests). I got `wp scaffold plugin-tests my-plugin` to run. But then at the next step when I try to run `bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root '' localhost latest` I get the following error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61)'
Check that mysqld is running on localhost and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet localhost 3306'
```

My local Wordpress site is running with MAMP (which is working). I'm not sure if that's relevant for the install script since I think it's creating a temporary DB to run the tests... Does it matter if it uses the built-in OSX mysql or MAMP's MySQL?

Here's the output from `wp --info`

```
$ ./vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp --info
PHP binary: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php
PHP version:    5.6.10
php.ini used:   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pipeline/wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 0.19.2
```

**Update 2**
I figured out that originally MySQL wasn't installed... that's why I couldn't connect! But now it is. I ran the install script, and this works...

```
$ ./vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp db tables
wp_users
wp_usermeta
wp_posts
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_terms
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_term_relationships
wp_commentmeta
```

But when I run `phpunit` I get this:

```
$ phpunit
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1452
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/install.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/install.php:21
PHP   3. require_wp_db() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-settings.php:79
PHP   4. wpdb->__construct() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php:350
PHP   5. wpdb->db_connect() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:649
PHP   6. mysqli_real_connect() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1452

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1452
```

Part of my problem is that I'm not clear on whether wp-cli should be running entirely on native (cli) PHP/Mysql, or MAMP's PHP/Mysql, or some combination of both.

**Update 4**
I'm pretty sure the final problem is that phpunit needs to be installed in MAMP, but I'm running it from OSX...

```
$which phpunit
/usr/bin/phpunit
```

Mentioned in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/markjaquith/2312948).

**Update 6**

It turns out you can no longer install phpunit using pear. So I added it as a composer dependency under require-dev, but when I run that version I get the same error!

```
$ ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1452
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/install.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/install.php:21
PHP   3. require_wp_db() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-settings.php:79
PHP   4. wpdb->__construct() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php:350
PHP   5. wpdb->db_connect() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:649
PHP   6. mysqli_real_connect() /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1452

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1452
```

I even added it to my path to be sure...

```
$ which phpunit
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pipeline/wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

**Update 7**

After reading the comments at the bottom of [this](https://trepmal.com/2014/02/22/getting-started-with-wp-cli/) blog post, I see that the install script was referencing the OSX version of `mysqladmin`. I'm not sure if this matters, but I prepended MAMPs version in the path, and re-ran the install script. It seems to install the Wordpress files in `/tmp/` anyway. Same error when I run `phpunit`

Comment: By default, [mamp runs mysql on port 8889](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/). Have you changed it ? What is the output of `telnet localhost 3306` ?

Comment: @Ploutox I did change it so MAMP runs mysql on the standard port. I added the output of `telnet` to the question above.

Comment: Yes it matters which `mysql` is being used.  Did you try exporting MAMP's `mysql` and `mysqladmin` as described here?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29990624/2646526

Comment: pls check if mysql runs via Terminal: `ps aux | grep sql`. Furthermore with this command you can check what runs on which port: `lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"`. If mysql is running on the correct port, do you have perhaps a firewall which gets into your way? Ohter option, can you connect to mysql if you run the command `mysql -uroot -p` in the terminal?

Comment: Could you go to http://localhost:3306 and see if a file named 'download' is downloaded? Otherwise your mysql is not running on that port(or not running at all).

Comment: @jerik I posted the transcripts of all three of your commands above. It looks like the first two are good, but the last one fails. Is this my problem?

Comment: @GuyT When I visit `localhost:3306` in the browser I get "Page not found: connection refused"

Comment: `ps` commands states that mysql is running, but at the `lsof` command no port 3306 is available, which is strange. The latter can explain the `mysql` command error. It seems that mysql is not listening on port *3306*, so your connection tries on port *3306* does not work. What does `mysqladmin -u root -p status` give you back. Have a look at `/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err` and `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf` perhaps you find there something strange...

Comment: regarding the `ps` command you have 2 times mysql running: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld` and `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe`. I am not sure if this is correct. In my opinion it should only be one

Comment: Regarding to this both should be running: http://serverfault.com/a/70623

Comment: If your user set up to run from `localhost` or an IP address?

Comment: @SamSwift MySQL user? Localhost

Comment: @SDP, yes, that's what I meant, sorry I wasn't very clear on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got `phpunit` to run!!

I couldn't find this documented *anywhere*...

At some point during the installation process, Wordpress core files are installed in `/tmp/wordpress/`. *That* Wordpress installation has it's own `wp-config.php` file which had incorrect values. When I corrected those values to match the `wp-config.php` of my site, `phpunit` worked without problems!

I'm not sure how this happened, but my theory is that the first time I ran the install script with the wrong credentials. But later I corrected them (I re-ran the install script several times). But I think the install script didn't overwrite the original files.

+400 to @Nikita Zernov for so much help!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MAMP, issue may be relevant to your MySQL Server settings. Make sure to check `Allow network access` option in MAMP settings:

[image]

**Update 1**

Create `phpinfo.php` file in your root directory (usually `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` for MAMP). Paste the following content:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Then check the `Loaded Configuration File` property. Open it using `nano` or other text editor in terminal. Then find and change this 3 properties`pdo_mysql.default_socket`, `mysql.default_socket`, `mysqli.default_socket` to your socket file.

Referenced from http://maccrazy.com/lion-upgrade-killed-my-php-site-and-how-i-fixed-it

Comment: Can the radio be set to "Only from this Mac"?

Comment: If you need to be able to connect to MySQL locally choose `only from this Mac`, otherwise `from other computers`

Comment: So I can run `wp db tables` and it works. But when I run `phpunit` it returns the "Unable to connect to database" screen...

Comment: Does Wordpress work? Does it connect to MySQL database?

Comment: I think so. Just added **Update 2** above, which elaborates

Comment: What do you see on line 1452 in `/private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php`? You can do that in OS X terminal by the following command: `nano +1452 /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php`

Comment: 1452: `mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
`

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7264459/2938258, so you will need to change `$socket` variable.

Comment: Should wp-cli be connecting to MAMPs mysql? Or OSXs? Or both?

Comment: It should connect to one where wordpress database is located, i think in your case it is MAMP's MySQL as you mentioned in your answer of this question.

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty sure that mean's MAMP. The reason it's confusing is that the install scripts seems to create a testing database also... which I'm pretty sure at the moment is in OSXs MySQL. Maybe that's my problem? Should I have run the test install script with the MAMP configurations instead?

Comment: It's also worth noting that I don't have `msyql.sock` in either of the locations mentioned in that other SO question

Comment: I am sorry about that. As your MySQL is running under MAMP, socket is located is here: `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: It's weird. I don't have `mysql.sock` in that location either.  I just upgraded to MAMP Pro 3.4

Comment: The webstart window says that's where it should be, but it's not. Very strange. Mysql on MAMP appears to be working fine in the mean time.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. Wordpress sites are connection to MySQL without problem. But still not the wp-cli unit tests. `phpunit`

Comment: Can you update your question with your php unit test file?

Comment: Done. **Update 3** above

Comment: I just discovered that I DO have `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`! It was hidden though. I'm not sure why

Comment: I added a symlink to the `mysql.sock` file. `wp ...` commands work and when I use `mysql` from the command line see MAMP databases etc. The only problem left is that `phpunit` seems to be looking in the wrong place still. I'm not sure, but the error above makes me think maybe I need to ALSO install phpunit locally, inside MAMP? ugh!

Comment: I checked and those settings were already properly set in the php.ini file.

Comment: I think we almost have this figured out... see **Update 4** above

Comment: Sure here's what I found: http://www.dolinaj.net/software-installation/mac/how-to-install-phpunit-with-mamp-on-mac/

Comment: I saw that too, but when I try to follow those instruction, pear installation fails for phpunit. I copied the output in **Update 5** above

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm running my local MAMP version of `phpunit` now, but it's doing the same thing. (**Update 6**) Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you ftp or telnet to localhost you'll get `conection refused`, if you want to fix the error change your `httpd.conf` to `ServerName localhost`

Also if you want to do remote login try enable remote login by going to
`System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login box (check it)`.

**For MySQL Problem**

Make sure ‘skip-networking’ is commented out in configuration file(in this case `/opt/local/etc/mysql55/my.conf`) or when starting mysql server, it does’t start with ‘–skip-networking’

In skip-networking mode, the mysql instance doesn’t “listen for TCP/IP connections at all. All interaction with mysqld must be made using named pipes or shared memory (on Windows) or Unix socket files (on Unix)” [from MySql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html)

Comment: MAMP appears to have it's own magical version of that property. In my.cnf I see `MAMP_skip-networking_MAMP`. Do you think I should comment this out? What is your theory?