# IOS - Composer uses an outdated PHP version

Tags: php, ios, composer-php

I just started a new Laravel project and got the message that my PHP is outdated.

> This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.36) does
>   not satisfy that requirement.

I ran php -v and it gave me this result `HP 5.5.36 (cli) (built: May 29 2016 01:07:06)`

I know I have a higher PHP version installed since my MAMP uses 7.0.

How can I make my machine/composer use this version of php instead of the 5.5 one?

Comment: It seems like you have installed both PHP versions, but only one can be used when you run the `php` command. So make sure that your `php` command uses your PHP7.0-cli instead of your 5.5 cli.

Comment: @Parziphal yes I know this, my question is how I can make it use the PHP7.0-cli

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4145667/697370) is very similar, perhaps a duplicate.

Comment: @JeffLambert This solution worked, thanks for the help

Comment: @NicolasDecroos No prob, glad to help. I'll go ahead and mark this one as a duplicate then.