# How to run composer on MAMP 's php version?

Tags: php, terminal, installation, composer-php, mamp

I can't run composer install because my php's version on my OS is not enough updated (5.5.36). So i tried to install composer globally with my MAMP's php(5.6.10)

1) I create alias for my MAMP's php

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php'
```

2)  Run this line to install composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | phpmamp
```

3)  Run this line to move composer

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Composer is installed (run composer on terminal works)

[This](https://gist.github.com/kkirsche/5710272) is a the tutorial.

But when i want to run `composer install`, composer uses my OS php.

Any idea ?

Comment: From a terminal, does `$ which php` output the same location as your `phpmamp` alias?

Comment: No it doesn't, output `/usr/bin/php`.

Answer (score 3):

Those lines worked for me. I override the OS PHP path to my MAMP PHP path.

```
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
$ export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can check the version by running :

```
$ which php
```

The complete [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path/#answer-29990624)

Thanks to @Andrew Patton

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it came up in web search for a similar issue I was having, and the latest version of MAMP Pro (mine is 6.6.2) has a GUI solution:

[image]

In Languages > PHP, under 'Default version', you should see a checkbox for "Also activate shortcut for Composer".

What this did for me is add an `alias` of `composer=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer` (in my zshell ~/.profile file on macOS Monterey). Maybe yours works similarly.

Of course, when switching PHP versions, it wouldn't also switch composer versions (which is necessary when switching between PHP 5 and 7.2.5+), so I have to use the OS install for one version and MAMP's for another. A little tricky, but if you don't have this problem, then the alias will be fine.