# How can I downgrade my php version with homebrew for MAMP?

Tags: php, homebrew, mamp

My php version is PHP 7.4.1.

But with MAMP, the highest possible php version I can use is 7.3.8.

So, when I try to open my webpage, I get the error message:

> Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher
> but the current PHP version is 7.3.8.

How can I downgrade my php version to fit to my MAMP version?

I tried:

```
brew install php@7.3
```

It was installed, but when I now write `php --version`, I get the error:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory

Comment: You can use your MAMP's PHP version to your command line's PHP. just link it

Comment: @ I made now `brew unlink php` and then `brew link --overwrite php@7.3 --force`. Now the php version is `7.3.13` but how can I get `7.3.8` ?

Comment: when I write `brew install php@7.3.8` I get the error `No available formula with the name "php@7.3.8"`

Comment: I think you're reading the error backwards. It says "the current PHP version is 7.3.8" but your composer.lock file requires 7.4 or higher. Doesn't that mean you actually need MAMP to use a 7.4.* version?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yes this would be great, but the highest Version available for Mamp is 7.3.8

Comment: Ok, so the underlying problem is that you ran `composer install` or `composer update` with the wrong PHP version. If you follow the steps in @MuhammadDyasYaskur's answer, composer should use the MAMP PHP version as well and you can re-generate the `composer.lock` file with the correct PHP version (you might need to delete the file first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need brew's PHP if you want to use MAMP's PHP.

just use `Applications/MAMP/bin/php7.3.8/bin/php --version` to use MAMP PHP, if you want to use as default command line, just link it to `/usr/bin`.

to link it run this to your command line:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

or

```
PHP_VERSION=`command ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

[check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path) for more detail.

PS: Maybe you should delete your brew php to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
$ brew update
```

and

```
$ brew upgrade php
```