# Why does cake/Console/cake.php use a different PHP version than the one set in the terminal?

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, mamp

I have now tried everything imaginable.

**The following problem occurs:**

In the terminal PHP runs in version PHP 7.4.12 from MAMP.

`php -v` output:

```
PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 13:28:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

When I output the path with `which php` I get this output:

```
 ❯ which php
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php
```

If I now in my CakePHP project in the cake.php `php phpinfo();` me using cake/Console/cake.php output, I get the PHP

```
phpinfo()
PHP version => 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS)
```

I have as far as possible the php version for the CLI modified. This in all imaginable files. In `~/.zshrc` the path is: `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin:$PATH`. Which was also confirmed with `which php`.

My System:

- MacOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3
- MAMP Pro Version 6.3
- CakePHP 2.10.24

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on stackoverflow after all. Note that this is only an excerpt from another answer. Which I also link here.
The post I found with a similar problem gives the following solution:

1. run the following:

```
export PHP_VERSION=`grep "alias php" ~/.profile | cut -d"/" -f6 | cut -c4-`
```

2. add the following to ~/.zshrc on top of it:

```
export PHP_VERSION=`grep "alias php" ~/.profile | cut -d"/" -f6 | cut -c4-`
export PHPRC="/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/" #point to your php.ini folder to use the same php settings
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php$PHP_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Here is the original post: [How to override the path of PHP to use the MAMP path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618229/13957465)